# How can I parse apparmor profile?

Tags: apparmor, selinux

I want to see the restrictions of `apparmor` for `dhclient` for example

I tried to run

```
 apparmor_parser -p /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/policy/profiles/usr.sbin.dhclient.6/raw_data
```

I got :

```
AppArmor parser error for /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/policy/profiles/usr.sbin.dhclient.6/raw_data in profile /sys/kernel/security/apparmor/policy/profiles/usr.sbin.dhclient.6/raw_data at line 1: Lexer found unexpected character: '' (0x4) in state: INITIAL
```

How can I see restrictions of apparmor to some process ? by looking at `/sys/kernel/security/apparmor/policy/profiles/` directory